# Install NGINX with SSL por443 over BottlePy port 80

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, bottle

I have an web-service created in BottlePy. Now it is on production.

But only serve to port 80.

I need an HTTPs solution, and I read that NGINX is a good solution.

But is it possible install NGINX without change BottlePy code?

Is it possible serve by port 80 in BottlePy and by port 443 in NGINX?

Some one can help me please?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I solve the problem:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen       443 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /xxx.key;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
    }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not reverse proxy ?

Comment: _Is it possible serve by port 80 in BottlePy and by port 443 in NGINX?_
i think this is possible but what happens is your site would be accessible in `http` as well.

Comment: I do not understand much of it. But the problem is when I do AJAX requests to the server and it responds with "The page at 'https://my_back_office.my_donain.com/profile.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://my_domain.com/service_profile'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
I did my service with bottlepy (port 80), and now I want to serve in the port 433 with HTTPs. But you want to keep the door 80 without https.
I never used NGINX before, or know how to use. I'm trying to learn now.